# SQL Join on case for a table made using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an output from a subquery

```
SELECT roll, marks FROM STUDENTS WHERE std in (1,2,3,4,5,6) and belongsTo in ('A', 'B', 'C') and subject = 'maths'
```

which I want to join to my table only in case when the value of a column from another table is Teacher.code = 1 else I don't want this above sub table to be considered

```
OTHER INNER JOIN AND SELECT TABLE STATEMENT
INNER JOIN (SELECT roll, marks FROM STUDENTS WHERE std in (1,2,3,4,5,6) and belongsTo in ('A', 'B', 'C') and subject = 'maths') GRADE  
ON CASE
WHEN Teacher.code = 1 THEN /* the above join should be used*/
WHEN Teacher.code= 2 THEN /* above join should not be used */
```

Comment: Why not just add `{Column Name} > 80` in the `JOIN`'s `ON` clause then? Am I missing something here?

Comment: sorry updated, question

Comment: My comment still stands, why not just change `{Column Name} > 80` to `Teacher.code = 1 `.

Comment: `WHEN Teacher.code = 1 THEN /* the above join should be used*/
WHEN Teacher.code= 2 THEN /* above join should not be used */`

Comment: If you don't want it to be considered, what *do* you want? No rows at all? Or return all rows from previous tables? If the latter, what should be shown for the columns of this table, nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
ON Teacher.code = 1 AND <join conditions> OR
   Teacher.code = 2
```

Presumably, if `Teacher.code` is neither `1` nor `2` the `ELSE 0` means you want nothing to match.

Comment: @FarhanAhmed . . . No, there is no need to use a `case` expression.